# Single Statement Code Contract (Guard Clause) without Exception or Conditional - Override Return

Tags: c#

What I'm really looking for is a Conditional Return Statement.  This is partially academic, but I'm curious how far the rabbit hole may go.

If we want to guard against executing with bad incoming data, we use Guard Clauses.  Code Contracts are a form of Guard Clause at the top of the method to establish a contract on the incoming parameter values.  These are some examples:

```
if (id <= 0)
{
    return null; // or throw exception
}
```

..

```
if (id <= 0) return null; // Same as above, though some hate single line conditionals.
```

..

```
Contract.Require(id <= 0); // <-- Throws Exception
```

Is there a way to perhaps override `return`, or create a new statement that stops execution of a method, that would look something like this:

```
public string GetName(int id) {
    returnif (id >= 0, null);

    // ... Do things
    // ... Do things
    return name;
}
```

It looks like a tuple return where the first thing is a boolean and the second thing is what to return if the boolean is false.  Otherwise, a return doesn't occur and the method keeps executing?

I know there is no conventional way.  I want to know what it would take to create a custom `returnif`, or if there are other non-conventional ways to accomplish this.

Comment: Sounds like you need code generation, or a new language.